# Way to keep a Window on top in Titanium?

Tags: window, titanium, z-index, titanium-alloy

It's a fairly straightforward task: I have a view/controller that is a persistent menu. This menu will be responsible for adding various other views/controllers as required. You know... like almost every app in existence.

As far as I can tell, however, there's no simple way in Titanium to tell a `Window` to stay on top. `zIndex` doesn't work on windows which is annoying because there is a method for doing this in the iOS, but it doesn't seem to be exposed in the Titanium SDK.

Am I missing something? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use slider menu by denial for both android and IPhone using titanium alloy

http://www.danielsefton.com/2013/05/slider-menu-widget-v2-for-titanium-alloy/

Thanks

Comment: That is a cool widget! I'll def keep it in mind. Still hoping for an answer to the question though. :)